# Gremlin bredcrumb query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm new to Gremlin and still learning.
I'd like to include the starting vertex in the results of the following:

```
g.V('leafNode').repeat(out()).emit()
```

This gives me a collection of vertexes starting from an arbitrary leaf node "upwards" to the root vertex. However this collection excludes the V('leafNode') vertex itself.

How do I include the V('leafNode') in this collection?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places for the emit in this statement: either before the repeat or after. If it comes before the repeat, it will be performed before evaluating the next loop.

Source: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step

So the following should take care of what your request.

```
g.V('leafNode').emit().repeat(out())
```